# Is there anyway to change the color of the highlighted text in a tkinter listbox?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to change the text color of a highlighted item in a Tkinter listbox and I can't find anything in the documentation for changing the text color. It seems like it is defaulted to a white text, and I would like it to stay the same color as depicted in my picture below. Also, bonus question: is it possible to not have the highlighted text underscored?

[image]

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both is possible. You can set the `selectforeground` of the listbox widget to change its color and set the value of `activestyle` to remove the underline.

Here is an example from [effbot page](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm), augmented with foreground color definition and without item underline:

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

listbox = Listbox(master, selectforeground='Black', activestyle='none')
listbox.pack()

listbox.insert(END, "a list entry")

for item in ["one", "two", "three", "four"]:
    listbox.insert(END, item)

mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir!

Comment: @JadonErwin My pleasure. ;)